# Как лучше хранить и выдавать динамическую информацию на Node.js

Tags: node.js, веб-сервер

У меня есть сервер на Node.js 
На него кидается через сокеты информация в небольших количествах, грубо говоря, массивы с 20-30 строковыми элементами не больше 30 символов каждый. 
На сервере информация сохраняется и хранится около 10 минут. В этот момент непрерывно посылается разная информация по сокету ну и ведет себя так же.
Теперь вопрос. Мне нужно организовать момент с выводом информации клиентам.
Как реализовать выдачу информации более правильно, чтобы меньше всего напрягался сервер. 
Например, можно подключаться к серверу по сокету и при подключении передавать всю имеющуюся информацию, и переодично выдавать что удалилось, и что добавилось. Либо можно выводить текущие данные при http запросе, и со стороны клиента делать ajax запросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы описали классическую задачу Instant Messaging/Notifications. Если хотите с меньшей нагрузкой и более удобной реализацией - используйте WebSockets. По сокетам можно пересылать информацию сразу после после получения, это делается только один раз и нет непрерывных опросов сервера как при Long Polling. На 2017 год WebSockets имеют широкую поддержку и они уже включены в стандарт W3C, нет смысла связываться с AJAX-запросами.

Comment: Да, в конечном итоге так и сделал) Спасибо!